# Multiple GCC versions resulting in multiple heaps, leading to crashes?

Tags: c, gcc

I've downloaded a Linux C SDK that comes with a bunch of static and dynamic libraries. The Readme has this to say:

> This SDK was compiled with the gcc version  4.5.1 .
>
> You SHOULD NOT mix this SDK binaries with other gcc versions, because
>   your application will end up in loading two different libcs, which
>   results in two different heaps. Mixing heaps will lead to application
>   crashes, when trying to free memory that was allocated by another
>   heap.

I've never heard of anything like this and a search on the web hasn't turned up any confirmation for it. What I did find, was something about the ABI, but as I understand it, this just means, that the libraries might be incompatible to my GCC version in the sense that they don't run at all. This has nothing to do with libc versions or the heap.

So, is it true what the Readme says? Or, in more general terms: Should I never try to use libraries I downloaded off the internet with another GCC version than the one they were compiled with?
What if I want to use several libraries that were compiled with different GCC versions?

Thanks everyone,
Moritz

Comment: I've not heard of anything similar.  I'd probably remove the SDK and go get one that doesn't promise trouble.

Comment: I've run code that was compiled with different libc and gcc versions without issue.  It might have something specific to do with that library and particular version of GCC though.  The readme claims it is specific to freeing memory, so it may be not generally an issue because by luck the same heap that allocated the memory frees it and they are trying to spare you from rare but hard to track down bugs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/dont-ask

Comment: It might be one of these SDKs that enforce use of a specific libc they deliver with the compiler suite. Like SDKs for embedded systems, which automatically link uclibc or dietlibc.

Comment: The vendors of the SDK seem to be confused, the C library is independent of GCC, so if they're worried about mixing C libraries it's largely irrelevant that it was compiled with GCC 4.5.1, maybe as fork0 suggests they mean it was compiled with a specific C library and using a different one (such as GNU libc) could be a problem ... but in that case only stating it was compiled with GCC 4.5.1 is pretty useless.

Comment: It's certainly true that this can happen. However the C library authors are aware of this and and have taken steps to ensure that the memory allocation pools are properly shared at least to some degree. This used to be a much more common problem on windows where you could end up with two copies of the _same_ c library loaded each managing it's own memory pool leading to this problem, but newer versions work around that problem too.

Answer (score -1):

It might be due to the optimisations used to build the SDK. Highly optimised binary has more chances of crashing if mixed.